# In Rainbow Six Vegas 2, in Story Mode, how far into the game is the "Ambush" section?

Tags: rainbow-six-vegas-2

I haven't played the story mode, and I was just wondering how far into the Story Mode the "Ambush" section is. For example, "there are 10 other sections before", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambush is in Act 1 Scene 2. I believe it to be the 5th section

Source: http://guides.gamepressure.com/tomclancysrainbowsixvegas2/guide.asp?ID=4544
(Right Hand Side)

Comment: Thank you! I will accept in 2 minutes which is how long I have to wait to accept.

Comment: Wow that site is very helpful! Screen shots and everything!=D THANKS!